# Is there any way of defining an array inside a class in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to make an array and an add function inside a class. add function will push some objects inside the array. There's a way to do it using prototypes, but is it possible by some other method, preferably defining the array inside the class (which is not possible I guess)?

```
//This works
class Parser {
    addOption(name, isReq, type, cantBeUsedWith) {
        this.options.push({
            name: name,
            isReq: isReq,
            type: type, 
            cantBeUsedWith: cantBeUsedWith
        });
    }
}

Parser.prototype.options = [];

//Need to do something like
class Parser {
    var options = [];
    addOption(name, isReq, type, cantBeUsedWith) {
        this.options.push({
            name: name,
            isReq: isReq,
            type: type, 
            cantBeUsedWith: cantBeUsedWith
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean initializing an empty `array` inside a `constructor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array in the constructor of your class:

```
class Parser {
  constructor() {
    this.options = [];
  }
  addOption(name, isReq, type, cantBeUsedWith) {
    this.options.push({ 
      name: name, 
      isReq: isReq, 
      type: type, 
      cantBeUsedWith: cantBeUsedWith 
    });
  }
}
```

---

By the way, your version where you set Parser.prototype.options is going to create a single array for the class, not one for each instance. This is probably not what you want to do. Doing `this.options.push` will mutate that single array, and therefore every instance of the class will see that mutation.

```js
class Example {
  addOption() {
    this.options.push('hello world');
  }
}

Example.prototype.options = [];

const a = new Example();
const b = new Example();
a.addOption();

console.log(b.options); // I never touched b, and yet its options changed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for class-level (as opposed to object-level) properties, there is currently no such option. There is a [`proposal-static-class-features`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features), which addresses this issue by adding public and private static methods.

If you want to add an object-level property, you simply intialize it in the contructor:

```
class Parser {
  constructor() {
    this.options = [];
  }
  addOption(name, isReq, type, cantBeUsedWith) {
    this.options.push({ 
      name: name, 
      isReq: isReq, 
      type: type, 
      cantBeUsedWith: cantBeUsedWith 
    });
  }
```